# Now to use Bluebird promises with Asana Node library?

Tags: bluebird, asana

I'm using the Asana Node library to create a new project with a series of sections (tasks) within the project. I need to create the sections in a specific order (synchronously) so they appear in the correct order in the project. If I just take an array of section names, then use forEach to add them as tasks, they don't appear in the correct order (because these are async calls). Here's a snippet:

> var sections = [
>   'Pre-Production',
>   'Production',
>   'Post-Production',
>   'Audio',
>   'Motion',
>   'Final'
>   ];
>   sections.forEach(buildSection);

I ended up having to string together a series of .then() calls, one for each section, in order to get them built in the correct order. There's obviously a better way, but I'm new to promises and bluebird. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See Bluebird's [`Promise.reduce()`](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#reducefunction-reducer--dynamic-initialvalue---promise) for sequencing a series of operations who's data comes from an array.

Assuming that `buildSection()` returns a promise when it is done and takes the section name as its argument, you could do this:

```
var sections = [ 'Pre-Production', 'Production', 'Post-Production', 'Audio', 'Motion', 'Final' ]; 
Promise.reduce(sections, function(val, item) {
    return buildSection(item);
}, 0).then(function(finalVal) {
    // all are done here
});
```

Bluebird's `Promise.reduce()` supports the accumulated `value` like `Array.prototype.reduce()`.  If you don't need that, you could also use `Promise.each()` or `Promise.map()` (with concurrency set to `1`) depending upon what type of final output you might want.